# WebStorm different ESLint config for each folder

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm, eslint, jetbrains-ide

I have JavaScript project which contain front-end and back-end folders. Each of those folders holds different ESLint config file. Problem is that I cannot setup WebStorm to auto detect ESLint for current folder. Is that possible or not? As I can see, it can be set only one ESLint per project which makes WebStorm unusable for JavaScript full-stack development. Is there any workaround?

In Languages and `Frameworks > JavaScript > Code Quality Tools > ESLint > "ESLint package"` points to `eslintrc` file in back-end folder. "Configuration file" is set to Automatic search option.

When I open file from front-end folder it did not apply lint from it's eslintrc, but from back-end folder. There is an error which shows that it search for plugin in back-end node_modules eslint folder instead of front-end one.

This means that *"WebStorm first looks for a .eslintrc or package.json in the folder with the file to be linted, then in its parent folder, and so on up to the project root"* **is not working**!

Comment: this should work just as described in Help if the automatic configuration is used. Do you have a single eslint installation in your project, or separate installations, one per folder, each with its own set of plugins? The latter is not currently supported (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25561).

Comment: @lena I have two eslints with different plugins. One for front-end folder and one for back-end folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support added in WebStorm 2019.1 EAP build https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25561